# Zoo:Visitor Registration form throws errors, doesn't render form when user is logged out, but not when logged in

Tags: safecracker, zoo-visitor, registration

So it looks like I'm having some issues with EE 2.5.5 and Zoo Visitor 1.3.21. I have a fairly simple registration template:

```
{embed="embeds/_header"}

  {exp:zoo_visitor:registration_form class="form-horizontal sign-up"}

    <header>

      <h6>Please fill out the following to create your BLOOM account.</h6>
      <p>All fields required.</p>

    </header>

    <fieldset>

      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="member_firstname">First Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" name="member_firstname" id="member_firstname" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="First Name" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="member_lastname">Last Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" name="member_lastname" id="member_lastname" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Last Name" />
          <p class="hint">Use this space for messaging about BLOOM&rsquo;s recommendation on how teachers should or should not change their username</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="email-address">Email Address</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="firstname.last@gmail.com" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input-xlarge" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="password_confirm">Confirm Password</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="password" name="password_confirm" id="password_confirm" class="input-xlarge" />
        </div>
      </div>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>

      <header>

        <h6>Choose your School and Grade</h6>

      </header>

      {field:member_school}

    </fieldset>


    <fieldset>

      <header>

        <h6>Add Your Class(es)</h6>

      </header>

      <div class="well">
        {field:member_classes}
      </div>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>

      <ul class="control-group btn-group">
        <li><button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">Sign Up</button></li>
      </ul>

    </fieldset>

  {/exp:zoo_visitor:registration_form}

{embed="embeds/_footer"}
```

And the registration form shows just fine if the user is logged in. However, if the user is not logged in (as you would expect from a registration page), I get a number of errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: EE is not defined index.php:657
    (anonymous function) index.php:657

Uncaught ReferenceError: EE is not defined signup:100
    (anonymous function) signup:100

2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < login:1

Uncaught ReferenceError: EE is not defined signup:70
    (anonymous function) signup:70
    p index.php:43
    l.fireWith index.php:44
    b.extend.ready index.php:33
    k.addEventListener.A index.php:42
```

Also, here’s the page output:

```
<html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>iPlan BLOOM</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.no-icons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/css/font-awesome.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/site.css">

    <script src="//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/assets/js/libs/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <header class="toolbar">

      <h1><a href="/"><span class="bloom">BLOOM</span> <span class="iplan">iPlan</span></a></h1>

            <nav class="account-navigation">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://local.upitt.com/account/signup">Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a class="btn btn-small btn-primary" href="http://local.upitt.com/account">Log In</a></li>                  </ul>
      </nav>

    </header>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://local.upitt.com/?ACT=3&amp;ui=core,widget,mouse,position,draggable,resizable,button,dialog,datepicker&amp;plugin=scrollable,scrollable.navigator,markitup,thickbox,toolbox.expose,overlay,tmpl&amp;v=1355874508&amp;include_jquery=y"></script>
<style type="text/css">  .playa-entry a span.open { color: #093 !important; }
  .playa-entry a span.closed { color: #900 !important; }
  .playa-entry a span.Super_Admins-id1 { color: # !important; }
  .playa-entry a span.Banned-id2 { color: # !important; }
  .playa-entry a span.Guests-id3 { color: # !important; }
  .playa-entry a span.Pending-id4 { color: # !important; }
  .playa-entry a span.Members-id5 { color: # !important; }
  .playa-entry a span.Content_Admins-id6 { color: # !important; }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://local.upitt.com/assets/themes/third_party/playa/styles/field.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://local.upitt.com/assets/themes/third_party/playa/styles/singleselect.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://local.upitt.com/assets/themes/third_party/matrix/styles/matrix.css?2.5.2">
<script type="text/javascript">PlayaFilterResources = {
  filterUrl: "http://local.upitt.com/",
  ACT: 23,
  lang: { is: "is" }
};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://local.upitt.com/assets/themes/third_party/playa/scripts/singleselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">new PlayaSingleSelect(jQuery("#member_school"), {"defaults":{"expired":"n","future":"y","channel":"8","limit":"0","limitby":"","orderby":"title","sort":"ASC"},"fieldName":"member_school"});</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://local.upitt.com/assets/themes/third_party/matrix/scripts/matrix.js?2.5.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">Matrix.lang = { options: "Options", add_row_above: "Add row above", add_row_below: "Add row below", delete_row: "Delete row", move_to_top: "Move to top", move_to_bottom: "Move to bottom", remove_file: "Remove File", select_file_error: "There was an error selecting your file. Please try again, or save and re-edit the entry if the problem persists." };</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://local.upitt.com/assets/themes/third_party/playa/scripts/matrix.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">PlayaColOpts.col_id_3 = {"defaults":{"expired":"n","future":"y","channel":"9","limit":"0","limitby":"","orderby":"title","sort":"ASC"}};</script>
<script type="text/javascript">function initMatrix_fd62c6a3bc0e043e308b57854aa60a3f(){var m = new Matrix("#member_classes", "member_classes", "Classes", [{"id":"col_id_3","name":"class","label":"Class","required":false,"settings":{"multi":"n","expired":"n","future":"y","channels":["9"],"orderby":"title","sort":"ASC"},"type":"playa","newCellHtml":"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"{DEFAULT}[selections][]\" value=\"\"\/><div id=\"{DEFAULT}\" class=\"playa playa-ss\" style=\"margin: 3px 0\" tabindex=\"0\"><table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" border=\"0\"><tr><td class=\"playa-ss-input\"><li class=\"playa-entry playa-ss-noval\"><a>Select an entry…<\/a><\/li><\/td><td class=\"playa-ss-button\"><img src=\"http:\/\/local.upitt.com\/assets\/themes\/third_party\/playa\/images\/select_btn_arrow.png\" alt=\"\" \/><\/td><\/tr><\/table><div class=\"playa-entries playa-ss-entries\"><div class=\"playa-scrollpane\"><ul><li class=\"playa-entry playa-ss-noval\"><a>Select an entry…<\/a><\/li><li class=\"playa-entry \" id=\"{DEFAULT}-option-5\" unselectable=\"on\"><a><span class=\"playa-entry-status open\">&bull;<\/span>Numbering curriculum, 101<\/a><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"{DEFAULT}[options][]\" value=\"5\" disabled=\"disabled\" \/><\/li><li class=\"playa-entry \" id=\"{DEFAULT}-option-6\" unselectable=\"on\"><a><span class=\"playa-entry-status open\">&bull;<\/span>Whatever happened to class?<\/a><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"{DEFAULT}[options][]\" value=\"6\" disabled=\"disabled\" \/><\/li><\/ul><\/div><\/div><\/div>","newCellSettings":false,"newCellClass":false},{"id":"col_id_4","name":"grade_level","label":"Grade Level","required":false,"settings":{"options":{"9th":"9th","10th":"10th","11th":"11th","12th":"12th"}},"type":"pt_dropdown","newCellHtml":"<select name=\"{DEFAULT}\">\n<option value=\"9th\">9th<\/option>\n<option value=\"10th\">10th<\/option>\n<option value=\"11th\">11th<\/option>\n<option value=\"12th\">12th<\/option>\n<\/select>","newCellSettings":false,"newCellClass":false}], [], 0, 0);
m.totalNewRows = 0;
};
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
initMatrix_fd62c6a3bc0e043e308b57854aa60a3f();
});
if (typeof(Bwf) != 'undefined'){
Bwf.bind('matrix', 'previewClose', function(){
initMatrix_fd62c6a3bc0e043e308b57854aa60a3f();
});
}</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (typeof SafeCracker == "undefined" || ! SafeCracker) { var SafeCracker = {markItUpFields:{}};}
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({dateFormat:$.datepicker.W3C+EE.date_obj_time});
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({defaultDate: new Date(1357335315000)});});
// ]]>
</script>
<style type="text/css">.hasDatepicker{background:#fff url(http://local.upitt.com/assets/themes/cp_themes/default/images/calendar_bg.gif) no-repeat 98% 2px;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:99%;}</style><script type="text/javascript">
                    $.createDatepickerTime=function(){
                        date = new Date();
                        hours = date.getHours();
                        minutes = date.getMinutes();
                        suffix = "";
                        format = "us";

                        if (minutes < 10) {
                            minutes = "0" + minutes;
                        }

                        if (format == "us") {
                            if (hours > 12) {
                                hours -= 12;
                                suffix = " PM";
                            } else if (hours == 12) {
                                suffix = " PM";
                            } else {
                                suffix = " AM";
                            }
                        }

                        return " '" + hours + ":" + minutes + suffix + "'";
                    }

                    EE.date_obj_time = $.createDatepickerTime();
                </script>

    <script src="/assets/js/min/main-min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/scripts/site.js"></script>

    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
    <script>
      var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];
      (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
      g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
    </script>

<ul id="matrix-menu" style="opacity: 0; display: none;"><li>Add row above</li><li>Add row below</li><li class="br"></li><li>Move to top</li><li>Move to bottom</li><li class="br"></li><li>Delete row</li></ul></body></html>
```

I've never run into this before, so I'm quite stymied. Any suggestions or help the community could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was that I hadn't enabled Guest Members to post to the Member channel. A quick trip to the Zoo Visitor troubleshooting tab revealed this section, complete with information on what to do next:
[image: An example of where I went wrong in Zoo Visitor]

Fortunately, all is resolved now!